# bootstrap datepicker not working when public app.js is loaded

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

why does datetimepicker does not work with the already-installed jquery3 in laravel. I need to at least load jquery 1.9.1 even though jQuery is loaded in app.js

**WORKING CODE:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js" defer></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js" defer></script>
```

**WORKING CODE WITH APP.JS IS LOADED:**

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js" defer></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js" defer></script>
```

**NON-WORKING CODE**

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js" defer></script>
```

Thank you in advance. The defer is just there since the scripts are in the head tag. Also, there are no errors in the console. The output of the non-working code is a pop-up but no date displayed.

Comment: I think the answer to the following question has been observed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50887462/bootstrap-datepicker-not-working-laravel-blade

Comment: well, it seems like i still need to load external (lower version) jQuery even though i already have jQuery installed in my project. that doesn't sound like a solution to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PLease use this one

Almost all web sites load jquery on header .

```html
<script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

write this code after include jquery will solve your problem

```html
 <script type="text/javascript">
            // When the document is ready
            $(document).ready(function () {

                $('#example1').datepicker({
                    format: "yyyy-mm-dd"
                });  

            });
        </script>
```